# Case when is not affect in function cast in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to select as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE v_test 
(
    id int,
    name char(4)
);

INSERT INTO v_test
    SELECT 1, NULL
    UNION
    SELECT 2, NULL

SELECT
    id,  
    CASE 
       WHEN name IS NULL
          THEN '   ' 
          ELSE CAST((LEFT(name, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(name, 3, 2) + ':00') AS TIME) 
    END AS test,
    name
FROM
    v_test;

SELECT
    id,  
    CASE
       WHEN name IS NULL
          THEN '   ' 
          ELSE '0'
    END AS test,
    name
FROM v_test;
```

The result from those queries looks like this:

[image]

You can see, result case when is not affect in function cast. Can someone explain detail for me.

Comment: The value produced by a `case` *expression* has to be of a specific type, which is based on all possible types from all `THEN` clauses and the `ELSE`. `time` has a higher precedence than `(n)(var)char` (and a `time` cannot contain an empty string anyway)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`case` expression will return only one `type`, in your first version you have two `type` one is `varchar` & other is `time`.

If, we look at `precedence` of type, then `time` has greater precedence than `varchar`.

So, you need conversion :

```
select id,  
       (case when name is null 
             then '   ' 
             else cast(CAST((LEFT(name,2)+ ':' + SUBSTRING(name,3,2)+':00') AS TIME) as varchar(255)) 
        end) as test,
       name 
from v_test;
```

Answer (score 1):

The sentence *"You can see, result case when is not affect in function cast."* makes no sense, I'm afraid. I *think* what you are asking  is why is the value `'   '` being displayed as `00:00:00.0000000`?

As per the documentation, [CASE (Transact-SQL) - Return Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#return-types):

> Returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in
>   result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression. For more
>   information, see [Data Type Precedence
>   (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

If we refer to the above linked document as well, this provides the (current) data type precedences:

> SQL Server uses the following precedence order for data types:
>
> 1. user-defined data types (highest)
> 2. sql_variant
> 3. xml
> 4. datetimeoffset
> 5. datetime2
> 6. datetime
> 7. smalldatetime
> 8. date
> 9. time
> 10. float
> 11. real
> 12. decimal
> 13. money
> 14. smallmoney
> 15. bigint
> 16. int
> 17. smallint
> 18. tinyint
> 19. bit
> 20. ntext
> 21. text
> 22. image
> 23. timestamp
> 24. uniqueidentifier
> 25. nvarchar (including nvarchar(max) )
> 26. nchar
> 27. varchar (including varchar(max) )
> 28. char
> 29. varbinary (including varbinary(max) )
> 30. binary (lowest)

Notice that `time` has a far higher precendence than `varchar`, thus your value `'   '` is implicitly cast to a `time`, and `CONVERT(time,'   ') = '00:00:00.0000000'`.